# Error creating a materialized view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build the following MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON EVENTS
   WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(AIRCRAFT, MONTHS_YEARS) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
  
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON  MANTEINANCE
   WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(AIRCRAFT, MONTHS_YEARS) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
  

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LOGBOOK
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1)) WITH ROWID
ON DEMAND
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
SELECT * FROM EVENTS e, MANTEINANCE m
WHERE e.AIRCRAFT = m.AIRCRAFT AND 
e.MONTHS_YEARS  = m.MONTHS_YEARS;
```

I created the logs associated with each table, also including the values inside the where clause, however, it gives me the error:

```
SQL Error [12052] [99999]: ORA-12052: no se puede realizar un refrescamiento rápido de la vista materializada MV_LOGBOOK
```

And I'm unsure why this is happening. Also, I would like to ask why I need a `ROWID` if there is already a `PK`.
Thanks.

Comment: Which of the 3 statements you’ve given is causing the error? Also, you really ought to learn ANSI SQL join syntax as the join syntax you’re using has not been considered good practice for 30+ years

Comment: The error message is clear: there is already a MV LOG on the table 'MANTEINANCE':
review the DDL of the object and try to understand who created it and when, if it's exactly the same it's probably just a manipulation error of yours.

Comment: @NickW could you elaborate why is this a bad practice? I also edited the error message, I selected the wrong one, sry

Comment: @p3consulting Sorry, I selected the wrong message. Is the fast refresh on MV_LOGBOOK that is giving problems.

Comment: ANSI JOIN syntax: it's simpler to write, understand and maintain; it's easier to change the join type (inner to outer etc); it separates the join logic from the filter (WHERE) logic. It's been the industry standard for 30+ years so if you use Oracle join syntax you give the impression of being out of touch with best practice - and people may wonder what other bad habits you've picked up :)

Comment: @NickW ah, I had understood that "Joins are not accepted in the FROM clause. Links between tables
must be stated in the WHERE clause (use Oracle proprietary syntax
for outer joins)." when using MV

Comment: That is correct. Can't use ANSI joins here. That said, an MV with joins must explicitly include the ROWID from each source table in the MV columns. You should explicitly name *every* column and not use implicit selects (i.e. "select * from ...").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An MV with joins must explicitly include the ROWID from each source table in the MV columns. You should also explicitly name every column and not use implicit selects, and use column aliases to differentiate columns with the same name because just like any table or view you can't have multiple columns with the same name:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LOGBOOK
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1)) WITH ROWID
ON DEMAND
DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
SELECT e.rowid e_rowid, 
    m.rowid m_rowid, 
    e.col1 e_col1, 
    e.col2 e_col2, 
    m.col1 m_col1, 
    m.col2 m_col2
FROM EVENTS e, MANTEINANCE m
WHERE e.AIRCRAFT = m.AIRCRAFT AND 
e.MONTHS_YEARS  = m.MONTHS_YEARS;
```